# CDC error "An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_ ..."

Tags: sql, sql-server, cdc

I'm using MS SQL 2014. Some tables have enabled CDC on its.
There is a problem: when I use function fn_cdc_get_net_changes_.. with parameter 'all' - query works without any problem.
But if I use parameter 'all update old' (to get data before and after changes) I get error:

> An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_ ...".

I've read many sources and found that such error raised when LSN's not valid.
But in my case it is not so!

```
select sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_Lager03'), sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()
-- 0x0016961C0002E34F0008   0x0016961C0002F8B90001

-- All OK
select * from cdc.[fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_Lager03](sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_Lager03'), sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 'all')
-- table with rows

-- An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_ ... .
select * from cdc.[fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_Lager03](sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_Lager03'), sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 'all update old')
-- empty table and error message in 'Messages' window
```

How make the function to work with the parameter 'all update all'?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `all update old` doesn't appear to be a valid filter parameter for the [net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522511.aspx) function. It's only specified for the [all](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510627.aspx) equivalent.

Comment: You are totally right! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Correct is
select * from cdc.[fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_Lager03](sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_Lager03'), sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 'all update old')

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Damien_The_Unbeliever**!

For parameter 'all update old' correct is cdc.[fn_cdc_get_**all**_changes_dbo_Lager03], not cdc.[fn_cdc_get_**net**_changes_dbo_Lager03]:

```
select sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_Lager03'), sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()
-- 0x0016961C0002E34F0008   0x0016961C0002F8B90001

-- All OK
select * from cdc.[fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_Lager03](sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_Lager03'), sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 'all')
-- table with rows

function cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_ ... .
select * from cdc.[fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_Lager03](sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_Lager03'), sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 'all update old')
```